# call to DJISDKManager.getInstance() hangs

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am trying to register a app with the DJI android SDK, but the call to DJISDKManager.getInstance() just hangs.

I am following the tutorial here: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html

After the app verifies it has all the required permissions it calls startSDKRegistration:
I have the call to DJISDKManager.getInstance() on a single line for testing.  It hangs on the call, and doesn't throw any errors.

```
private void startSDKRegistration() {
        if (isRegistrationInProgress.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            Thread registrationThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showToast("registering, pls wait...");
                    try {
                        DJISDKManager temp = DJISDKManager.getInstance();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), new DJISDKManager.SDKManagerCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRegister(DJIError djiError) {
                            if (djiError == DJISDKError.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) {
                                showToast("Register Success");
                                DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();
                            } else {
                                showToast("Register sdk fails, please check the bundle id and network connection!");
                            }
                            Log.v(TAG, djiError.getDescription());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProductDisconnect() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onProductDisconnect");
                            showToast("Product Disconnected");
                            notifyStatusChange();

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onProductConnect(BaseProduct baseProduct) {
                            Log.d(TAG, String.format("onProductConnect newProduct:%s", baseProduct));
                            showToast("Product Connected");
                            notifyStatusChange();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProductChanged(BaseProduct baseProduct) {
                            // there was nothing in the tutorial for this method
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComponentChange(BaseProduct.ComponentKey componentKey, BaseComponent oldComponent,
                                                      BaseComponent newComponent) {

                            if (newComponent != null) {
                                newComponent.setComponentListener(new BaseComponent.ComponentListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onConnectivityChange(boolean isConnected) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onComponentConnectivityChanged: " + isConnected);
                                        notifyStatusChange();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG,
                                    String.format("onComponentChange key:%s, oldComponent:%s, newComponent:%s",
                                            componentKey,
                                            oldComponent,
                                            newComponent));

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInitProcess(DJISDKInitEvent djisdkInitEvent, int i) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDatabaseDownloadProgress(long l, long l1) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            GlobalParams.getInstance().getThreadPool().submit (registrationThread);

        }

  private void notifyStatusChange() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);
        mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 500);
    }

    private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    };

    private void showToast(final String toastMsg) {

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs after Android Gradle plugin version 3.6.0+
https://developer.android.google.cn/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-6-0-behavior

> Native libraries packaged uncompressed by default
> When you build your app, the plugin now sets extractNativeLibs to "false" by default. That is, your native libraries are page aligned and packaged uncompressed. While this results in a larger upload size, your users benefit from the following:
> Smaller app install size because the platform can access the native libraries directly from the installed APK, without creating a copy of the libraries.
> Smaller download size because Play Store compression is typically better when you include uncompressed native libraries in your APK or Android App Bundle.
> If you want the Android Gradle plugin to instead package compressed native libraries, include the following in your app's manifest:

```xml
<application
    android:extractNativeLibs="true">
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: What is the setting for `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`?

I ask because there is a known issue with the values.  I don't remember exactly but setting  the following should work.

```
minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 29
```